# BLE on Xamarin Cross Platform

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

In Xamarin.Form cross platform , is there any way to show the list of available BLE devices (after scan) in a pop-up dialog box or in menu list and then connect the desired BLE device from the pop-up dialog box and show the data on the UI created for displaying data ??????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need [`DependencyService`](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/dependency-service/) to retrieve the list of available BLE devices and just display to the [`ListView`](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/working-with/listview/) as usual.

Besides, below component made by Xamarin may help you to find BLE devices easily for both iOS and Android.

https://components.xamarin.com/view/Monkey.Robotics

Answer (score 0):

Xamarin doesn't provide cross-platform BLE support out of the box. There are a few 3rd-party libraries providing cross-platform BLE functionality, one of which I wrote after spending 1-2 years on a native BLE project: https://github.com/nexussays/ble.net

There is a complete Xamarin.Forms project for iOS, Android, and UWP (https://github.com/nexussays/ble.net/tree/master/test/ble.net.sampleapp) that provides the exact functionality you asked for -- scan, display results, connect, display dialog, etc. But to briefly cover the API here...

You can scan thusly:

```
await adapter.ScanForDevices(
   ( IBlePeripheral peripheral ) =>
   {
      // check if this is the device you want to connect to
      // e.g., query peripheral.Advertisement.Services
   },
   cancellationTokenSource.Token );
```

And to connect to read/write/notify characteristics:

```
var connection = await adapter.ConnectToDevice( peripheral, TimeSpan.FromSeconds( 5 ));
if(connection.IsSuccessful())
{
   var gatt = connection.GattServer;
   var value = await gatt.ReadCharacteristicValue( someServiceGuid, someCharacteristicGuid );
   await gatt.WriteCharacteristicValue( someServiceGuid, someCharacteristicGuid, new byte[]{ 1, 2, 3 } );
   // etc...
}
else
{
   Debug.WriteLine( "Error connecting to device. result={0:g}", connection.ConnectionResult );
}
```