# Cross platform bluetooth development solutions

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I made a little heart rate monitor app with Unity, but trying to ship it to Windows, the bluetooth part isn't cross platform.

Are there existing cross platform (mac/windows, linux too would be nice but not a dealbreaker) bluetooth solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there isn't a "pure" cross-platform solution where you can write one application that works across multiple platforms. This is because the underlying stack for different OSes/platforms is different because the hardware is different for them. The closest thing to a cross-platform solution might be Xamarin as theoretically you can write an application that works for Android/iOS/Windows. Have a look at the links below:-

- [Developing Cross-platform BLE Apps](https://punchthrough.com/developing-cross-platform-ble-apps-our-experience/)
- [ble.net: cross platform BLE library](https://github.com/nexussays/ble.net)
- [BLE on Xamarin Cross-platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28803246/ble-on-xamarin-cross-platform)
- [The smart BLE Guide: Add BLE to your app with Qt and Flego](https://blog.felgo.com/smart-bluetooth-le-guide-add-ble-to-qt-app)

Comment: Ah this is what I was coming to understand after trying a number of demos and tutorials out. Thanks a lot!

Comment: "because the hardware is different for them" -- how so? A bluetooth dongle is a bluetooth dongle and should work on any OS that supports USB and BT.

Comment: Yeah, I don't think it is actually impossible, since BLE is a standard, its just difficult and nobody has done it yet. In particular, Android is annoying because it does not have native (C/C++) bindings for BLE APIs, you have to do Java/Kotlin code.